# JasperReports with Java Bean: Failed to render image (the field of InputStream type)

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Input:
 1. class with member InputStream

```
public class Dateien {
...
   private InputStream payload = null;
...
   public InputStream getPayload() {
       return payload;
   }
   public void setPayload(InputStream payload) {
     this.payload = payload;
   }
}
```

1. payload contains Stream with image (jpg or other formats)
2. Jasper report with text field (class=java.lang.String, expression=$F{file.payload}) shows me right string in report

   ```
   java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@6aa27760
   ```
3. but when I create Image field in report `(class=java.io.InputStream, expression=$F{file.payload})`
4. I get exception

   ```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/abc] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Image read failed.] with root cause
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Image read failed.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageReader.readImage(JRJdk14ImageReader.java:73)
   ```

What should I do to fix the problem?

By the way: I tried to get the image stream via HTTP in browser and I see good rendered image. So I see the stream is OK and not corrupted.

Comment: As you can from the source code of *net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageReader*, the code raised the exception is: `if (image == null)
  {
   throw new JRException("Image read failed.");
  }`

Comment: @Alex K Thanks. But as you see in my text above (p.2) I have no NULL in Stream objects. I have good (not null) stream objects.

Comment: As you can see, the *JRJdk14ImageReader* operates the `byte[]` type. The full code of method is: `public Image readImage(byte[] bytes) throws JRException
 {
  InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

  Image image = null;
  try
  {
   image = ImageIO.read(bais);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   throw new JRException(e);
  }
  finally
  {
   try
   {
    bais.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
   }
  }

  if (image == null)
  {
   throw new JRException("Image read failed.");
  }

  return image;
 } `

Comment: You can debug this line: `image = ImageIO.read(bais);`

Comment: @Alex K Pls make you solution as post. I will mark it up. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: You are welcome :) `Pls make you solution as post` - I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception raised in the [*net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageReader*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRJdk14ImageReader.html) class, in line number 73.

The source code of *`JRJdk14ImageReader.readImage(byte[])`* method:

```java
public Image readImage(byte[] bytes) throws JRException
{
    InputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    Image image = null;
    try
    {
        image = ImageIO.read(bais);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new JRException(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            bais.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
    }

    if (image == null)
    {
        throw new JRException("Image read failed."); // the line #73
    }

    return image;
}
```

As we can see, the Exception is thrown in case the *image* is still null.

You should check that you are really passing the array of bytes (`byte[]`) to the report as  *payload* field.